# How to edit custom customer group attribute (column) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-attributes

Bonjour !

I try to edit some custom customer group fields in my Magento 2.3 but I don't know how to start.

I already have added some columns and displayed it in admin back-office with a module.

view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_group_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_group_columns">
        <column name="siret">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">SIRET</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="code_client">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Code client</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="zipcode">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Code postal</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

But now I want on the update form to have the capability to modify this fields (siret, code_client, zipcode)

[image: Screenshot of the BO]

For exemple, here I only have 2 fields but I want to add for example the zipcode in the form.

[image: Screenshot of the update form]

Thanks ;)

Comment: Have you solved the loading of customer fields in edit page?

Comment: I am facing issue on adding custom filter in Customer Group .
Could you please help me out on adding custom filter in Customer Group. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm also, working on a similar solution.
We have to extend the magento/module-customer.

Check this two files:
Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php
Controller/Adminhtml/Group/Save.php

In the form you add:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'CustomField',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'fieldname',
                'label' => __('CustomField'),
                'title' => __('CustomField'),
                'class' => 'validate-number'


            ]
        );
```

And in the Save.php after these two lines:

```
$customerGroup->setCode(!empty($customerGroupCode) ? $customerGroupCode : null);
$customerGroup->setTaxClassId($taxClass);
```

Your save your custom field.

```
$CustomField= $this->getRequest()->getParam('CustomField');
$customerGroup->setCustomField($CustomField?:0);
```

Not sure if you have to also override these:

Model/Data/Group.php

Model/ResourceModel/GroupRepository.php
To create the method `"setCustomField"`

Of course, you need to extend it in your own module.

(This is my first answer in this forum, so forgive-me if is something missing)

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form` class to your custom module.

Try like below :

> app\code\Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

/**
 * Adminhtml customer groups edit form
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form
{
    //Add new field using $fieldset->addField()

}
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I extend my module and now I try to display the field SIRET, and I modify the file Form.php.

The field is display but the field is not filled.

[image]

I try to modify the Save.php, Group.php

//Save.php

```
 $siret = $this->getRequest()->getParam('SIRET');
 $customerGroup->setSiret(!empty($siret) ? $siret : null);
```

//Group.php

```
public function getSiret()
{
    return $this->_get(self::SIRET);
}

public function setSiret($siret)
{
    return $this->setData(self::SIRET, $siret);
}
```

// GroupRepository.php

```
    public function getById($id)
{
    $groupModel = $this->groupRegistry->retrieve($id);
    $groupDataObject = $this->groupDataFactory->create()
        ->setId($groupModel->getId())
        ->setCode($groupModel->getCode())
        ->setTaxClassId($groupModel->getTaxClassId())
        ->setSiret($groupModel->getSiret());
    return $groupDataObject;
}
```

I add setSiret() everywhere in the file where we had setTaxClassId().

But it doesn't work, can someone help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: What file should I override ?